# Macro to count tokens in a define

Tags: c, macros, count, token

I am looking for a way to count the number of tokens of which a `#define` is composed.
For example, consider the following lines of code:

```
 #define DAYS_OF_WEEK MON TUE WED THU FRI SAT SUN

 class DaysOfWeek
 {
 public:
 static const int count = COUNT(DAYS_OF_WEEK);
 };
```

The example is very trivial and COUNT is invented, just to let you known about the issue.
At the moment, I do not know any C macro that returns 7 in place of COUNT().

Thanks for your help

Comment: So you want to ask how to count the number of words in a string?

Comment: This cannot be done with a macro. It's possible to get close (using a different syntax -- if you were to separate each token with a comma) but it makes for some extremely ugly preprocessor code. Converting the definition to a string and counting words at runtime, as @devnull suggests, is probably better.

Comment: c ? c++ ? And how do I use it elsewhere? `#define COUNT_DAYS_OF_WEEK 7`

Comment: Why not do this with `enum { MON, TUE, WED, THU, FRI, SAT, SUN, COUNT };`?

Comment: @user694733 Nah, too readable and makes too much sense.

Comment: use GCC Extension : `#define S(x) #x
#define COUNT(x) ({ char *p = (char[]){S(x)};int i=0; for(;strtok(p, " ");p=NULL) ++i;i;})
`

Comment: token lists separated by space usually have not much application in C. What do you need this for? As @mah said, if that would be comma separated, there would be tricks to do it. Also ou seem to confound C and C++. Your tag says C and your example code is C++.